# Consumir REST API em Node.js + cURL

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, libcurl, restful

Sei que há vários pacotes em `Node` para consumir `REST API` mas preciso de algum que utilize `cURL`. Por algum motivo (que não descobri) não consigo autenticar com as existentes.

Tentei https://github.com/danwrong/restler e https://github.com/aacerox/node-rest-client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Então converti um cliente em `PHP` para `Node.js`.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vps-rest-client

É um wrapper (não sei como seria isso em pt) nesse [pacote](https://github.com/JCMais/node-libcurl) que por sua vez é um wrapper no `cURL`.

A utilização é algo assim:

```
var host = 'https://api.budgetvm.com/v2/dns/record';
var key = 'some___key';
var domain_id = 'some___id';

var rest = require('vps-rest-client');
var client = rest.createClient(key, {
  verbose: false
});

var post = {
  domain: domain_id,
  record: 'test.example.net',
  type: 'A',
  content: '111.111.111.111'
};

client.post(host, post).then(function(resp) {
  console.info(resp);

  if (resp.success === true) {
    client.get(host + '/' + domain_id).then(function(response) {
      console.info(response);
      client.close();
    });
  } else {
    client.close();
  }
}).catch((err) => console.info(err));
```